# Angular 1 removes slash from ng-style

Tags: angularjs, css

I need to display a ellipse cut in half and am using the elliptical corners of CSS3, *i.e.*:

```
return {
    'border-radius': '50% / 100%';
    'border-bottom-left-radius': 0;
    'border-bottom-right-radius': 0;
};
```

I serve the computed CSS via `ng-style` to the element but Angular seems to remove the slash from the css resulting in faulty css. I serve other shapes as well, so i need to calculate the CSS

I tried both `'50% \/ 100%'` and `'50% / 100%'`, with or without spaces, none worked. All produced the same result.

Here is what I get in the style explorer in Chrome:

[image]

Is Angular removing the slash? How can I bypass that behaviour?

This is the console log right before it returns it to `ng-style`:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to escape the slash, something like this: `return {
    'border-radius': '50% \/ 100%'; };`

Comment: can you try calculating the value at where you return it so that it would look like 'border-radius': '0.5%' when passed via ng-style?

Comment: simply return this `'border-radius':'50% 100% 0 0'`

Comment: If you are looking for simple ellipse cut in half, so it means, its curved in the same side and the other ends will be straight. Why cant you use simple as this border-radius : 50px 0px 0px 50px

Comment: @I.R.R., I actually put that in the description of this post but i guess it removed it, so I tried that as well.

Comment: @I.R.R., see the pic I added of the console right before it goes to ng-style